# Hotlink Protection : How to set to allow only from server requests and some domains?

Tags: php

I want to prevent direct access to my php file. How can I set that it will response to requests only from server OR domain1.com OR domain2.com? I need php code.

There is a sample which I use this code to response to only server requests :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header('location:http://www.sitename.com/error.php');
    exit;
}


echo " 

TEST

";
?>
```

Comment: Check the value of the referer to see if it's in your domain.

Comment: Note that referer can easily be spoofed.

Comment: why would you want to prevent direct access? if you programm the code inside well, there should be no issues when someone finds your filename on accident

Comment: I have a streaming site and I hide subtitles to echo "" codes. So I dont want somebody to access to subtitles directly.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether the referer contains your domain in the URL. You can use a regular expression to test multiple domains.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || !preg_match('#^https?://[^/]*(?:domain1|domain2)\.com/#', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header('location:http://www.sitename.com/error.php');
    exit;
}
```

Replace `domain1` and `domain2` with your actual domains.

Comment: I have tried it and unfortunatelly it is not working.

Comment: I forgot the ending `#`.

Comment: Yes I know you forgot it. But still it is not working. I can access the file directly.

Comment: Your original test should handle accessing the file directly. This is only for use after you get past that test, to check that the link is from an acceptable site. But I've put them together into a single test.

Comment: I have tried your last codes but nothing changed. It doesn't allow direct access but it doesn't allow to domains which are defined in codes, too. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me. What does `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` show when it should allow direct access?

Comment: Hello Barmar. I have edited my question as "How can I set that it will response to requests only from server OR domain1.com OR domain2.com?" . So I have a code which it will give response to any file's request which are hosted in same domain OR it will give response to domain1.com's files request. Let me give the example : My player is hosted in domain1.com and my subtitles are hosted in domain.com. Each subtitle is in php file like codes in my question. TEST word represent subtitle content. So how can I setup my codes to do what I want?

Comment: Are you talking about AJAX requests, or another PHP script is using `file_get_contents()` to read the subtitle from domain.com?